# How to properly generate a documentation with Swagger for Flask

Tags: python, flask, swagger, openapi

I would like to ask how to generate a proper documentation with Swagger for Flask. I have tried many libraries like flasgger, apispec, marshmallow, flask_apispec, etc but I didn't find the best one.

So I have a function here:

```py
@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def test_function():
    data = request.get_json()
    validated_data = TestSchema().load(data)
    # Doing something here
    return jsonify({'data': 'success'}), 200
```

I already have a schema object with marshmallow as follows:

```py
class TestSchema(Schema):
    id = fields.Int(required=True)
    name = fields.Str(required=True)
```

I want to automatically generate the documentation so that it is easier to know how to call my test API. How can I do this with swagger UI? I'm not really familiar with web programming and APISpec things, so it is inconvenient for me to generate it manually by writing a yaml file. I would like to use the marshmallow schemas if possible

Answer (score 4):

Swagger is an open-source software tool that helps developers design, build, document, and consume RESTful web services. It allows you to generate interactive API documentation for your Flask-based web services.

To generate documentation with Swagger for Flask, you can follow these steps:

**1. Install the necessary dependencies:**

```
pip install flask flask-restful flask-swagger
```

**2. Add Swagger to your Flask app by importing it and initializing it:**

```
from flask_swagger import swagger
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
swagger = Swagger(app)
```

**3. Decorate your API methods with Swagger decorators to provide the required metadata.**
Here's an example:

```
from flask_restful import Api, Resource
from flask import Flask
from flask_swagger import swagger
from flask_swagger_ui import get_swaggerui_blueprint

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
swagger = Swagger(app)

class HelloWorld(Resource):
    def get(self):
        """Return a hello world message"""
        return {'message': 'Hello World!'}

api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/hello')

# Swagger documentation route
@app.route('/swagger')
def get_swagger():
    swag = swagger(app)
    swag['info']['version'] = "1.0"
    swag['info']['title'] = "My API"
    return jsonify(swag)

# Swagger UI route
SWAGGER_URL = '/swagger-ui'
API_URL = '/swagger'
swaggerui_blueprint = get_swaggerui_blueprint(
    SWAGGER_URL,
    API_URL,
    config={
        'app_name': "My API"
    }
)
app.register_blueprint(swaggerui_blueprint, url_prefix=SWAGGER_URL)
```

Run your Flask app and go to http://localhost:5000/swagger-ui to see the generated documentation.

Note: Make sure to update the info dictionary with your API's title and version. You can also customize the appearance of the Swagger UI by passing additional options to the get_swaggerui_blueprint function.

**EDIT**

**With the use of Marshmallow Schema**

Define your associated Marshmallow schema

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields

class UserSchema(Schema):
    id = fields.Integer()
    name = fields.String(required=True)

class UserListSchema(Schema):
    users = fields.List(fields.Nested(UserSchema))
```

Define your API endpoints

```
from flask import jsonify, request

@app.route('/users', methods=['GET'])
def get_users():
    users = [
        {'id': 1, 'name': 'Alice'},
        {'id': 2, 'name': 'Bob'},
    ]
    return jsonify(UserListSchema().dump({'users': users}))

@app.route('/users', methods=['POST'])
def create_user():
    user_data = request.get_json()
    user = UserSchema().load(user_data)
    # create user logic here
    return jsonify(UserSchema().dump(user))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you show me the part that I can use Marshmallow Schema to generate the documentation?

Comment: Hey @juliussin
I have edited the answer for Marshmallow schema. I guess something like this might work. Please check it out

Comment: could the schema be shown on the swagger UI?

Comment: yes, i think so it can